# Recovering a matrix from a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I have a matrix $G\in R^{10\times 10}$ of rank 2 (which is an approximation to a symmetric and psd Gram matrix). How can I recover a Matrix $P\in R^{10\times 2}$ from $G$ such that $G=P P^T$?

Comment: Is $G$ symmetric and PSD also ?

Comment: For now, let's say it is. But later it might not be.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Please edit your question's body to include it.

Comment: "But later it might not be" Then later this task is impossible, as $P^TP$ _is_ symmetric and psd.